# Only column name in where clause

Tags: sql, presto

```
with preparation as(
select a,
       b,
       c,
       regexp_like(a, 'example1|example2') as example
from database_X
)

select *
from preparation
where example
```

I have a query that looks like above and it seems to pull correct results. However, I do not understand how using only column name in where clause functions. Could anybody please explain how it works or refer me to any articles or something that explains the logic?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clause requires a boolean condition and [`regexp_like`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_like#regexp_like) returns a boolean, basically that's it. I.e. any expression resulting in a boolean is valid for `WHERE`, for example:

```sql
select * 
from table
where true
```

or

```sql
select * 
from table
where 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP_LIKE return boolean so you can use "example" in the where condition.
It's the same query (but shorter) than :

```
with preparation as(
select a,
       b,
       c,
       regexp_like(a, 'example1|example2') as example
from database_X
)

select *
from preparation
where example is true
```